# How to delete boxes or line object in pine script which are back more than 500 or max_bar_back limit?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am new to trading and recently created block boxes or zones using the if statement and the `box.new` function. A function has created the boxes from the first bar and now I try to delete those boxes which are crossed by the price using a for loop. In doing so, the boxes which are older than 500 or more bars back are not getting deleted. How can I delete the boxes which are farther behind than the `max_bars_back` limit?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.